# constraints break with only one constraint in the problematic constraints list

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

i'm getting this error

```
2016-12-13 17:55:51.948 ME[462:128656] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want.
Try this:
    (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect;
    (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it.
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x16fee810 H:[ME.Checkbox:0x16ff3060(0)]>"
)
```

i'm trying to get [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1W1HDXz5bIrd3hEWUgySHBLWnc/view) (attached video) behavior, which actually works. `Checkbox` is a custom `UIButton` that have two images set to it for two different states.
I changed the background color of `Checkbox` to yellow for it to be more clear in the simulator.

in `init()` of `Checkbox` i'm constraining the width to 0 and i change this value through the constant of the constraint when i drag the text bubble.
these text bubbles are a custom `UITableViewCell` and i only get this error some of the times.

what can it be?

attached code:

this custom view is added to the `contentView` of `UITableViewCell` and I'm using a custom class to add constraints.

```
class TextBubble: UIView {

    var bubble: EmptyBubble!

    var checkbox: Checkbox!

    var textLength: Double!

    var label: UILabel!

    var isNcalc = false

    var checkboxConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint]?

    var maximumCheckboxSize: CGFloat = 0

    init(text: String, isNcalc: Bool) {

        super.init(frame: CGRect.zero)

        self.alpha = 0
        self.isNcalc = isNcalc

        bubble = EmptyBubble()
        self.addSubview(bubble)

        checkbox = Checkbox()
        self.addSubview(checkbox)
        self.maximumCheckboxSize = Checkbox.checkedImage?.size.width ?? 0

        if checkboxConstraint == nil {
            print("add")
            checkboxConstraint = checkbox.constrainWidth(0)
        } else {
            print("HUZAAAA!!")
        }

        checkbox.alpha = 0

        label = UILabel()

        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.textAlignment = .natural
        label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        if isNcalc {
            label.textAlignment = LangUtil.getTextLang() == "he" ? .right : .left
        }
        label.textColor = UIColor(hex: 0x586C76)
        label.text = text

        bubble.content.addSubview(label)
        label.stretchToBoundsOfSuperView()

        textLength = Double(text.characters.count)


        if LangUtil.isDeviceHebrew() {
            checkbox.constrainToRightOfSuperView(0)
        } else {
            checkbox.constrainToLeftOfSuperView(0)
        }

        checkbox.centerVerticallyTo(self)
        checkbox.constrainToTopOfSuperViewLessThan()
        checkbox.constrainToBottomOfSuperViewLessThan()

        bubble.anchorToRightGreaterThan(checkbox, padding: 0)
        bubble.centerVerticallyTo(self)
        bubble.constrainWidthLessThanSuperView(0.8)


        bubble.constrainToTopOfSuperViewLessThan()
        bubble.constrainToBottomOfSuperViewLessThan()


        if isNcalc {
            bubble.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(bubbleTapped(_:))))
            bubble.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        }

    }

    @discardableResult
    func snapCheckbox() -> Bool {

        if let currSize = checkboxConstraint?.first?.constant {
            let show = 1.5 * currSize > maximumCheckboxSize
            showCheckbox(show)
            return show
        }

        return false

    }


    func setCheckboxSize(_ delta: CGFloat) {

        if let currSize = checkboxConstraint?.first?.constant {

            let divider = delta > 0 ? 6 : 5
            let newSize = currSize + (delta / divider)
            if newSize >= 0 && newSize <= maximumCheckboxSize * 1.9 {
                checkboxConstraint?.first?.constant = newSize
                self.checkbox.alpha = newSize / maximumCheckboxSize
            }

        }

    }

    func bubbleTapped(_ tap: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if checkbox.isVisible() {
            checkbox.sendActions(for: .touchUpInside)
        }
    }


    func showCheckbox(_ show: Bool) {

        let duration = bubble.isVisible() ? Constants.ANIMATION_DURATION : 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: Constants.ANIMATION_DURATION, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseOut, .beginFromCurrentState, .allowUserInteraction], animations: {
            self.checkboxConstraint?.first?.constant = show ? self.maximumCheckboxSize : 0
            self.checkbox.alpha = show ? 1 : 0
            if duration > 0 {
                self.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        } , completion: nil)

    }


    override func didMoveToSuperview() {
        super.didMoveToSuperview()
        if superview != nil {
            self.constrainWidthLessThanSuperView(1)
        }

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

Comment: This warning comes when the duplicate constraints added.

Comment: To answer, we'd need to know _all_ the constraints that affect this view.

Comment: So you're getting the intended effect, but a constraint is being broken? Can you add a picture of your constraints in IB or the code (if they're created programmatically)?

Comment: @salman-ghumsani I tried to print where I add this constraint and it didn't print when I got this error again, so it doesn't appear that I'm adding this constraint twice.

Comment: @toddg yes, I do get the intended effect. I will attach the code now, I do create the constraints in code.

Comment: Do you get the error when you drag or when the view is initialized?

Comment: @toddg yes, i do get this error only when i drag, and i also suspect that it happen when I drag and a new text bubble is added to the `UITableView` but the constraint it not being added twice.